# Picking a hotkey

Tags: windows, linux, macos, global, hotkeys

In my application I want to have a hotkey, something like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.  The I don't want to clobber any operating system shortcut, or third party program (such as a launcher).  The program runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

What's the best way to pick a hotkey which doesn't clobber any other programs?

Edit: This is mean to hide developer access from users.

Comment: On Windows, for example, within your app you can use any short-cut you like, so long as it doesn't use the Windows key as a modifier - those are reserved for the system. Certain moronic device software register system wide hot-keys and when these clash with your app's shortcuts it is not pretty. I'm thinking of software supplied alongside certain Intel graphics processors that would rotate your screen when you press CTRL+ALT+arrow key. As I use that shortcut in my app, I had a lot of angry clients complaining about what **my**app was doing to their machines!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you give users the ability to choose their own hot-key combination.

Comment: @gravitron yes but he must still supply a different map of shortcut depending on the target OS to provide a better OOTB experience.

Comment: 99% of users (assuming your user base is not a bunch of geeks) will not change the shortcut mapping. So why provide this ability at cost to both developer and user?

Comment: Why alienate your users that have some program you've never heard of that chose the same hot-key combination?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Qt, so check [`setShortcut`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qaction.html#details)

Answer (score 0):

Just pick an easy enough hotkey that you don't remember any uses of, and google it with words "windows", "linux", "mac os", "hotkey" and such. If you have searched for all the above and don't find anything useful, then this hotkey is probably "free".

Of course there is no guarantee that no third party program will be using it, but if any big enough program is using it, you will easily find it with google.

But yea, the best way to go is to make the hotkey modifyable in your settings.